# Layout Run Fail

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm getting a layout run failure whenever I try to set a layout type override and I'm not sure what is causing it.

I have a parent view that has a tabpanel as a child item:

```
Ext.define('InventoryDemo.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
        'InventoryDemo.view.brand.Brand'
    ],

    title: '<h1>Inventory Demo</h1>',
    layout: 'border',

    items:[
        {
            ...
        },
        // This is the tab panel that I'm trying to add the container class to
        {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            title: 'Inventories',
            header: false,
            region: 'center',
            reference: 'inventoryTabSet'
        }
    ]
});
```

And this is the view I'm trying to add as a tab to the tab panel:

```
Ext.define("InventoryDemo.view.inventory.list.Inventory",{
    extend: "Ext.container.Container",
    xtype: 'inventory',

    ...

    closable: true,
    layout:{
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'grid',
            bind:{
                store: '{inventory}'
            },

            listeners:{
                itemclick: 'showDetails'
            },

            columns:[
                { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Price', dataIndex: 'price' },
                { text: 'Active', dataIndex: 'active' },
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

This works if I don't include the layout config:

```
    layout:{
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
```

If that's left out, the view loads without issue, but when I include the hbox type I get a run fail.

I tried looking through the call stack, but honestly I'm still to green to sencha to see what's causing the error:

> [E] Layout run failedlog @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:8732logx @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:8768Ext.apply.log.log.error @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:8771Ext.define.handleFailure @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:214144Ext.define.runComplete @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:214616callOverrideParent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:1348Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:11711Ext.override.runComplete @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:61413Ext.define.run @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:214610Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:61421Ext.define.statics.resumeLayouts @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:61436Ext.resumeLayouts @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:66954Ext.define.notify @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:92658Ext.define.onTick @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:92677(anonymous function) @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:6416(anonymous function) @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:6606
>   3ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:8732 [E] Layout run failedlog @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:8732logx @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:8768Ext.apply.log.log.error @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:8771Ext.define.handleFailure @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:214144Ext.define.runComplete @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:214616callOverrideParent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:1348Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:11711Ext.override.runComplete @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:61413Ext.define.run @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:214610Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:61421Ext.define.statics.resumeLayouts @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:61436Ext.resumeLayouts @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:66954privates.statics.notify @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:116731privates.statics.onTimer @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:116750Ext.Function.fireHandlers @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444523987794:6303

Is there something about how I have the views set up that would cause a fail when trying to use any layout type other than the default?

Comment: Consider why you are using a `hbox layout`. When you only have one item a `hbox` it is not necessary. Default is `layout: fit` I guess so that would be enough to stretch your grid to the max. But yes, if `hbox` is needed the answer of @Navaneeth-Kesavan is correct.

Comment: The above is right on point. Why would you use a box layout there?

Comment: I'm using the hbox here because when you click a row in the grid I'm adding a detail form panel to the right with the selected record loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When layout of a container is set to `hbox`, children of that container are expected to have a `flex` or `width`. If you specify `flex` or `width` for the `grid`, then you will not face layout run failure.

Here is a fiddle for you:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v9a

Comment: also when the grid is inside a panel with layout set to vbox it is necessary to set its width.